# Testing PHPMailer username and password without sending, i.e. check connection

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer with an email account that has to have its password changed every 90 days.

Is it possible to check the PHPMailer connection to the account without actually sending an email? Ideally I would like a button that the user clicks titled 'Check Connection', which then returns 'Connection Successful' or 'Connection Not Successful'.

Note, this is not to check if you can connect to the SMTP, but actually check the username and password and return a result.

I saw somewhere someone mentioned using the Connect() function, but I cannot get this working.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add what you have tried so far ?

Comment: After setting the initial instance, I tried the following:
  if($mail->Connect()){

    echo "Connection successful";

  }else{

    echo "Connection error";

  }

Answer (score 10):

You do know that you already have some code that shows how to do this? It's [one of the examples provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps).

Here's the bulk of it:

```
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new SMTP instance
$smtp = new SMTP;
//Enable connection-level debug output
$smtp->do_debug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;
try {
    //Connect to an SMTP server
    if (!$smtp->connect('mail.example.com', 25)) {
        throw new Exception('Connect failed');
    }
    //Say hello
    if (!$smtp->hello(gethostname())) {
        throw new Exception('EHLO failed: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
    }
    //Get the list of ESMTP services the server offers
    $e = $smtp->getServerExtList();
    //If server can do TLS encryption, use it
    if (is_array($e) && array_key_exists('STARTTLS', $e)) {
        $tlsok = $smtp->startTLS();
        if (!$tlsok) {
            throw new Exception('Failed to start encryption: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
        }
        //Repeat EHLO after STARTTLS
        if (!$smtp->hello(gethostname())) {
            throw new Exception('EHLO (2) failed: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
        }
        //Get new capabilities list, which will usually now include AUTH if it didn't before
        $e = $smtp->getServerExtList();
    }
    //If server supports authentication, do it (even if no encryption)
    if (is_array($e) && array_key_exists('AUTH', $e)) {
        if ($smtp->authenticate('username', 'password')) {
            echo "Connected ok!";
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Authentication failed: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'SMTP error: ' . $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

To connect using SMTPS rather than SMTP+STARTTLS, change this line:

```
if (!$smtp->connect('mail.example.com', 25)) {
```

to:

```
if (!$smtp->connect('ssl://mail.example.com', 465)) {
```

Comment: Are there any way to do this with ssl connection? Because with tls works, but with ssl doesn't do.

Comment: That's because you have to decide *before* you connect if you want to use SMTPS. I've added info on how to do that in my answer.

Comment: how about skip certificat verification for self-signed certificates?

Comment: Found the answer after digging into both the phpmailer and the smtp class. you need to add a timeout and then you can pass additional options. Ex: ```$stmp->connect('ssl://mail.example.com', 465, 30, ['ssl' => ['allow_self_signed' => true]])```

Comment: No, you don’t have to do that. There is a property specifically for that called [SMTPOptions](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#property_SMTPOptions).